# How to detect whether full video watched by user or not in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I am developing an iPhone app in which functionality is like to give credit to user if user has watched full video.

But I don't know How to detect whether full video watched by user or not in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect way to find that. 
You need to make logic for that. but it's not 100% true in each case. Below is a logic which I used in my one of the project. but as I told it's not perfect.

You need to find total duration of the video.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player;
float length = player.duration;
```

After that you need to make a timer for this duration.

```
NSTimer *checkForFullWatchVideoTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:length
                                                                        target:self
                                                                      selector:@selector(videoDidFinish)
                                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                                       repeats:NO];
```

Now if this timer get fire than it means user has watch complete video.

```
-(void) videoDidFinish{
    // User has watch complet video.
}
```

if before that event user dismiss this movie player conroller then you need to remove this timer using invalidate method.

```
[checkForFullWatchVideoTimer invalidate];
```

This is the way I have implemented. But if user seek the timer in movie player controller then this logic will not work. you may be achieve this by using AVPlayer controller. I hope this will work for you.